# Why does my controller isn't matching with view?

Tags: angularjs, web, view, controller, pug

I'm new to angular/jade and i can't understand why does my controller isn't working in my view, i can't use my variable set in my controller.

Here is the controller code :

```
angular.module 'app'

.controller "DirectoryGridCtrl", ($scope, Refs) ->

  ################################################################################
  # actions                                                                      #
  ################################################################################

  ################################################################################
  # onLoad                                                                       #
  ################################################################################

  $scope.test = "Test"

  ################################################################################
  # constructor grid                                                             #
  ################################################################################

  @grid = new Grid(resource: Directory, ctrlName: 'directoryGrid')

  ################################################################################
  # return                                                                       #
  ################################################################################
  return
```

I've tried with vm.test, test, scope.test, $scope.test, etc..

Here is the route :

```
angular.module 'app'

.config ($stateProvider) ->

  $stateProvider
    .state 'app.directory.grid',
      url: ''
      templateUrl: 'app/modules/directory/grid/directory-grid.html'
      controller: "DirectoryGridCtrl as vm"
```

Here is where i'm trying to use it but it is never printed :

```
  {{::vm.test}}
  {{::refs.userList}}
```

Should i create other files? Or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: No console errors? In the markup, are the interpolation bindings within your `DirectoryGridCtrl`'s scope?

Comment: No cosole errors ! I don't really get what do you mean in your second question but all the controller used before this one works perfectly

Comment: Your controller needs to be attached to the DOM, and your bindings should be within the controller's scope. Something like: `<div ng-controller="DirectoryGridCtrl"> {{ yourBinding }} </div>`

Comment: I am working with Jade, not html is it the same method?

Comment: The principle is the same, but you should use Jade syntax, of course. The salient point is that the bindings need to be nested within the element where the controller is attached, so that those values are in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using scope just use

```
 {{::test}}
```

also change the state as,

```
 $stateProvider
    .state 'app.directory.grid',
      url: ''
      templateUrl: 'app/modules/directory/grid/directory-grid.html'
      controller: "DirectoryGridCtrl"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is still not working. Nothing is printed